# ¡investigar antes de preguntar!

Tags: discusión

Es obligatorio que un Usuario indique en su post donde ha realizado investigación sobre sus dudas, para garantizar que ha realizado un esfuerzo mínimo de investigación?

si el usuario no demuestra lo anterior, es motivo de cierre?

Me parece que no, cuando un usuario no proporciona esta informacion; me parece que se le debe solicitar en un comentario antes de emitir votos de cierre al post.

en este post, no se emitió ningún comentario que alentara al usuario a arreglar su publicación antes de ser cerrada.

Doy un ejemplo he visto muchas preguntas sobre configuración de cristal report y conexión a base de datos donde solo dejan una cadena de texto de ejemplo y una imagen del error que da la aplicación ... no hay investigación, no hay código y no esta relacionado a un problema especifico de programación pero estas preguntas si son aceptadas.

*En estos dos ejemplo yo le pido mas información los usuario,
no es motivo para cierre:*
[Problema con Crystal Report](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/491328/problema-con-crystal-report)
[Error genérico en GDI+ al imprimir en crystal report](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/437005/error-gen%c3%a9rico-en-gdi-al-imprimir-en-crystal-report)

La pregunta del OP no esta basada en un lenguaje de programación, es un lenguaje de marcado pre-implementado para después crear diseño (HTML), no es un problema de ejecución o visibilidad a los que estan acostumbrados; no puedes se puede esperar un ejemplo con un código de partida que puedas reproducir y obtener un null exception point.

> *HTML Semántico es el uso de las etiquetas HTML para reforzar la semántica, o el significado, de la información en las páginas web más que simplemente redefinir su forma de presentación (apariencia). El HTML semántico es procesado por los navegadores web regulares así como por muchos otros agentes de usuarios.*

Pregunta de referencia:

***Pregunta basada en diseño y semántica***

[Cual es la estructura de html5?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/491680/cual-es-la-estructura-de-html5)

hago la salvedad de que la ayuda siguiente de stack overflow:

> Busca, e investiga
> ...y mantén un registro de lo que encuentres. Incluso si no encuentras una respuesta útil en cualquier parte del sitio, incluyendo en los enlaces sobre preguntas relacionadas o que no hayan ayudado pueden ayudar a otros a entender cómo tu pregunta es diferente del resto.

**Nota:** *Claramente se esta refiriendo a buscar preguntas anteriores en el sitio para evitar la duplicidad. y citarlas en la pregunta si encuentras algunas que ayude o no ayude en el nuevo post.*

Comment: Es obligatorio demostrar que has investigado y que has intentado. Todo esto ayuda a la redacción de una buena respuesta.

Comment: me refiero a que eso no esta en las normas del sitio @Christian agregar la investigación es una solicitud de quien responde ... no es obligatorio y no es una norma ... y lo que dice la ayuda, se refiere a buscar dentro del sitio antes de hacer una pregunta duplicada... o a clarificar por que tu pregunta es diferente a otras ya existentes...

Comment: @Christian el no agregar la investigación no debe ser un motivo de cierre si nadie lo ha pedido en un comentario ...

Comment: cuantas preguntas a cerca de nullpointer exception existen? creo que varias y cada una de esas tiene algo distinto y por eso no han sido cerradas como duplicadas. Antes de escribir tu pregunta si debes de buscar en el sitio y si encuenras una solución que no te ha servido es recomendable adjuntar el enlace para ahorrarle trabajo a otros usuario que vayan a dar una solución que el OP ya ha probado

Comment: @Christian estas repitiendo lo que te estoy diciendo ... no hay nada acerca de lo que pregunto el OP en el Sitio y la escusa que dio MOD gbinchi no esta relacionada al motivo de cierre.

Comment: Bueno en resumen si debe ser cerrada o reportada como "necesita detalles o aclariones" ya que el usuario no ha descrito su problema con todos los detalles para poder dar una solución

Comment: la semántica no es un problema; es una interpretación de normalización y marcado de etiquetas que tampoco esta en la documentacion oficial... tienes conocimiento de HTML semántico ???

Comment: te doy un ejemplo he visto muchas preguntas sobre configuración de cristal report y conexión a base de datos donde solo dejan una cadena de texto de ejemplo y una imagen del error que da la aplicación ... no hay investigación, no hay código y no esta relacionado a un problema especifico de programación pero estas preguntas si son aceptadas.

Comment: Esas preguntas son de baja calidad, aparte que los errores deben colocarse en forma de texto. Tal vez la publicación no alcanzó la cantidad de votos de cierre, los usuarios pasaron de largo por ser de baja calidad o simplemente usuarios nuevos respondieron esas preguntas por que no saben el funcionamiento del sitio

Comment: por que son de baja calidad ??? que criterio te lleva a pensar que es de baja calidad??? no es un error.... lo que reporta el OP todos los post tiene que ser sobre errores???

Comment: pues nop, hay preguntas sobre el funcionamiento interno de python, C, C++, etc. Son de baja calidad por su contenido. ya sea por falta de detalles, mala redacciónn (que no se entienda) o que cumpla cualquier opción de reporte

Comment: pero ese no es el caso; la pregunta no esta basada en un lenguaje de programación, es un lenguaje de marcado pre-implementado para después crear diseño, no es un problema de ejecución o visibilidad a los que estas acostumbrado; no puedes esperar un ejemplo con un codigo que puedas reproducir un null exeption point...

Comment: HTML Semántico es el uso de las etiquetas HTML para reforzar la semántica, o el significado, de la información en las páginas web más que simplemente redefinir su forma de presentación (apariencia). El HTML semántico es procesado por los navegadores web regulares así como por muchos otros agentes de usuarios.

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo, una pregunta no debe ser cerrada así nomás. Siempre hay que dejar un comentario primero.

Comment: @DanteS. mira que ahora que revise nuevamente ese post; el BOT **Comunidad** aporto mas que todo los votos negativos y el cierre. que tristeza ...

Comment: Que hizo el bot?

Comment: Comento esto: ***Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.***

Comment: @DanteS. el tema es que las dudas sobre semántica no tiene un problema especifico...

Comment: Pero es una realidad que se espera que el OP investigue, lo cual es dificil y no agregó en su pregunta. Esas cosas no son bien recibidas. Y no es por que la pregunta no muestre un ejemplo minimo y verificable, si no por que no tenía ese detalle.

Comment: @DanteS. y en el tour ... no dice nada al respecto... como puedes saber si tu pregunta será bien recibida cuando hay algo que no esta descrito tácitamente en el mismo tour que te mandaron a leer... yo lo dije, yo busque y no encontre nada en el sitio referente al tema .... y si busque fue para no dar una respuesta a una pregunta que podia ser duplicada... por que la ayuda dice eso ***BUSCA en el SITIO*** en ningún lado menciona que debes poner lo que hayas o no encontrado por internet ... incluso nadie se lo pidió o explico, hasta que yo llegue y le comente...

Comment: @DanteS. demostrar que investigo con un link puede perderse con el tiempo si ese host se cae ... entonces si ese fuera el caso de cierre que era lo que esperan que dijera el OP ***he buscado y no encontré nada sobre este tema***? WTH...

Answer (score 11):

La falta de investigación previa no es per se un motivo de cierre, es uno de los motivos claros para votar una pregunta negativamente, como de hecho explica el desplegable que aparece sobre el botón de voto negativo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestión es que esta falta de investigación previa normalmente (no siempre, pero suele concurrir) deriva en otros problemas que si son causa de cierre, como por ejemplo el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resumiendo: la falta de investigación previa no es motivo de cierre, pero suele hacer que la pregunta no tenga la suficiente calidad para permanecer abierta.

P.D. Veo mucha preocupación con el cierre de preguntas, y me gustaría aclarar que los cierres de preguntas no son definitivos. La preguntas se cierran para evitar que reciban respuestas que probablemente sean de baja calidad dada la falta de información de la misma. Pero si el autor edita su pregunta para solucionar los problemas indicados, esta automáticamente pasa a la cola de reapertura con lo que, si la pregunta termina teniendo la calidad necesaria para el sitio, esta se reabrirá sin problemas.

Y, como aclaración extra, Stack Overflow en Español no se caracteriza precisamente por su alto nivel de cierre de preguntas, mas bien al contrario. Esta es una de las razones que motivó que se solicitara que el numero de votos necesarios para cerrar una pregunta pasase de 5 a 3.

**Editado**

En un par de comentarios se expresan dudas sobre como puede saber el OP cual es el problema con su pregunta si no se le ha indicado en un comentario. Por un lado, es bastante raro que nadie comente en preguntas de este estilo indicando los problemas. Pero es que además el sistema automáticamente muestra al autor de la pregunta el motivo de cierren con enlaces a la ayuda para que pueda mejorarla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola esto era lo que esperaba ver...  y esta claro que esto solo lo ve en qie vota negativo. la ayuda del sitio no describe esta situacion o no lo deja claro en el tour, un usuario nuevo. no conoce sobre este tema, por eso despues de este post publique otro en meta. en rl cual incluya como advertencia la importancia de presentar una investigacion.

Comment: en el caso de la pregunta sobre semantica, para mi como respondedor me quedo claro, al hecharle un ojo a la pregunta y conocer sobre semantica me parecio raro que el usuario haya hecho esa pregunta, parecida a preguntar si un <tr> es hijo de un tag <table> lo vi absurdo, pero no pude calificar la pregunta de baja calidad o que le faltaran detalles sin antes corroborrar que la documentacion no lo haya aclarado. al visitar la focumentacion comprobe que hay un vacio o una laguna. y dan a entender que esas tag no necesariamente tienen un orden especifico. por eso califique la pregunta como buena

Comment: al ser una pregunta de sobre la comprencion de semantica, y no de error yo me senti incapacitado de pedir codigo de ejemplo, incluso el ambito de la misma pregunta, me llevo a pensar que el usuario por lo. minimo si sabe de la existencias de esas etiquetas debio investigar... no son comunes...

Comment: yo antes de responder busque si existian otras preguntas similares sobre semantica (en el sitio) y no encontre nada... con el objetivo de evitar duplicidad... por suerte no veo preguntas de SEO que usen los tag de google... por que tendrian que ser cerradas me imagino...

Comment: entonces, yo estoy creando este post en donde se modifique la ayuda, para que esto quede claro para quien publica una pregunta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5270/cambio-en-la-ayuda-de-c%c3%b3mo-elaboro-una-buena-pregunta

Comment: otra cosa que no me queda claro es: cerraron la pregunta por algo que el OP no ve (hace falta rn la ayuda) , quien lo ve es el que vota negativo o reporta la pregunta para cierre... ok, se propone que se agregue a la ayuda lo que hace falta, y tambien votan negativo... es contradictorio... ***hay un dicho para esto... ni usan el hacha ni la prestan...***

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent te sigues basando en que la pregunta fue cerrada por falta de investigación y no es asi. La razón de cierre es _esta pregunta necesita detalles o clarificación_ que creo que es un texto bastante descriptivo. Por eso yo no veo necesario modificar la ayuda, esta simplemente dice que antes de preguntar se pide un esfuerzo de investigación previa

Comment: @Piloh esto se debatio ayer en el chat, gbianchi dijo que por falta de investigacion, otro dijo que parecia spam, y otro dijo que baja calidad... nadie emitio un comentario aclaratorio al OP. que detalles le hace falta? , yo fui el. unico que le pidio al OP que aclarara que havia investigado...

Comment: Pero el OP no siempre sabe que es lo que debe modificar en su pregunta. Si descubre que la cerraron y nadie dejó un comentario, entonces que pensará el OP?

Comment: @DanteS. exacto por ese motivo, puse en meta la solicitud para que las descripción se mas explicita y menos genérica ...

Comment: @DanteS. he editado mi respuesta para aclarar tu duda

Comment: Gracias por la edición c: Sin embargo, a mi me parece un mensaje muy generico. Un ejemplo minimo y verificable es considerado un detalle por el OP? Se que para nosotros si lo es, pero no se si para el OP.

Comment: @DanteS. el mensaje de un ejemplo minimo y verificable enlaza con la ayuda, concretamente con [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), que da una información mucho mas exhaustiva que la que puedes añadir en un comentario

Comment: Eso es algo bueno c: Supongo que por eso nadie deja un comentario.